# SQL Query - Iterate based on condition

Tags: sql, loops

I have a table of Countries. 
I want to write a query to schedule a match between every country and no match should be repeated.I do not want to use for loops.

[image]

Comment: I'd do a self join.

Comment: `and no match should be repeated` ... Japan vs. Bangladesh appears twice.

Answer (score 4):

With a self cross join:

```
select
  t1.name TeamA,
  t2.name TeamB
from tablename t1 cross join tablename t2
where t1.name < t2.name
order by t1.name, t2.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7gSwfsqmhr8dPv4JUfpdde/2).
Results:

```
| TeamA      | TeamB    |
| ---------- | -------- |
| Bangladesh | China    |
| Bangladesh | India    |
| Bangladesh | Japan    |
| Bangladesh | Pakistan |
| China      | India    |
| China      | Japan    |
| China      | Pakistan |
| India      | Japan    |
| India      | Pakistan |
| Japan      | Pakistan |
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Cross Join:

`SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM test a
CROSS JOIN test b
where a.name < b.name`

Here is a demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8zBxQ3w7N5cmHBJ4PDDV6V/1

Comment: Will duplicate the games, since it returns both A vs B, and B vs A.

Comment: @jarlh I edited my response, I added '<>' instead of '<' . Thank you for noticing!

Comment: That's much better.